# Regex Change Space Separated Items To Comma Separated Items

Tags: python, regex

I have this regex to change a list that is separated by spaces to a list separated by commas, `re.sub(r'(\w+)', r'\1,', text)`, but I need it to only match if the line starts with `xyz`, like this:

```
xyz a bcd ef --> xyz a,bcd,ef
```

But should not change any thing for a line that does not start with `xyz`, like this:

```
xy abc def #Nothing changes
```

This `xyz .*(\w+)` does not work, because it only matches the `xyz a bcd` and does not separate the `a` and the `bcd`.

Comment: What do you mean by "the list terms don't "share" the xyz"?

Comment: That was poorly worded, sorry. It matches only the xyz a bad, and does not do worst I want.

Comment: Could you give us some additional examples of what you want to do? It's not completely clear to me.

Comment: Neither do I. Could you please give a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example => http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Reformat the question like this ---> 1. Your string 2. Your regex that you tried and output that you got. 3. The desired output that you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
if re.match(r'xyz', text):
    line = text.partition('xyz ')
    text = line[1] + line[2].replace(' ', ',')
```

Comment: `^xyz` would me more suitable in this case.

Comment: match automatically searches from the beginning of the string only

Comment: Best way to check if a string starts with a literal is by using [`str.startswith`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith).